# Posted an array of string in ReactJS but got one string in WebAPI

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webapi

I tried to post an array of string from ReactJS to WebApi but I got just one string [0].

Here is my ReactJS code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export const FileUpload = () => {

  const [files, setFiles] = useState();
  const [fileNames, setFileNames] = useState();

  const saveFile = (e) => {

    var tempfiles = files;
    if (tempfiles == null) {
      tempfiles = [];
    }
    tempfiles.push(e.target.files[0]);
    setFiles(tempfiles);

    var tempFileNames = fileNames;
    if (tempFileNames == null) {
      tempFileNames = [];
    }
    tempFileNames.push(e.target.files[0].name)
    setFileNames(tempFileNames);
  };

  const uploadFile = async (e) => {
    debugger
    const formData = new FormData();

    //upload many
    for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      formData.append("Files[${i}]", files[i]);
      // formData.append('FileNames[${i}]', fileNames[i]);
    }

    //upload 1
    // formData.append("FormFile", file);


    //add test data
    formData.append('TestField', 'abcxyz');
    formData.append('FileNames', fileNames);
    formData.append('ProjectId', 123);
    formData.append('NameToDisclose', false);
    //

    try {
      //upload many
      const res = await axios.post("https://localhost:44376/api/test/UploadMany", formData);

      ////upload 1
      // const res = await axios.post("https://localhost:44376/api/test/Upload", formData);

      console.log(res);
    } catch (ex) {
      console.log(ex);
    }
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input type="file" onChange={saveFile} />
      <input type="button" value="upload" onClick={uploadFile} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Here is my Controller:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System;
using UploadFileToWebApiBE.Model;

namespace UploadFileToWebApiBE.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class TestController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("UploadMany")]
        public ActionResult Post([FromForm]UploadFileMany files)
        {
            try
            {
                files.Files = Request.Form.Files;

                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status201Created);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError);
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Here is my UploadFileMany:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;

namespace UploadFileToWebApiBE.Model
{
    public class UploadFileMany
    {
        public string TestField { get; set; }

        public IFormFileCollection Files { get; set; }

        public string[] FileNames { get; set; }

        public int ProjectId { get; set; }

        public bool NameToDisclose { get; set; } = false;
    }
}
```

This is the data from ReactJS:

[image]

This is the data from WebApi:

[image]

I want to have 3 items for FileNames, not one item seperated by a comma.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try to pass filenames as a JSON string by using:

`formData.append('FileNames', JSON.stringify(fileNames);`

and then parse the JSON string in your back-end codes. because i remember that formData in JavaScript doesn't accept arrays and objects as input. You can stringify them and pass your arrays and objects in a standard format.
I hope this works for you

Comment: Still one string but it becomes Json string: ["New Microsoft Word Document.docx","text1.txt","New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx"]

Comment: @anhtv13 : So it's OK.If you look at  `["New Microsoft Word Document.docx","text1.txt","New Microsoft Excel Worksheet.xlsx"] ` carefully you'll see it's an array with 3 strings . just parse the JSON string and you'll have an array with 3 items.

Comment: Yes I can deserialize it into array string. Your solution doesn't give me straight 3 strings but anyway it solves the problem. I give you an upvote. Thank you :)